# dynamic dependant select options with flask python

Tags: python, html, dynamic, flask, html-select

I am new with Flask. I am trying to find how to generate dependant select (html) options. That is, I have two selects: The first one gets options from database (this is not the problem) and the second one display options depending on the first select. Let's say if first select options are:

- Meat
- Vegetables

The second select will display the following:

If **meat** was selected:

- pork
- chicken

If **vegetables** was selected:

- zucchini
- tomato
- carrots

I have found some solutions but all of them require using jquery. Is there any way to avoid using jquery and do it only with flask?

Comment: Are you willing to POST/reload the whole page after the first select ? If yes, it shouldn't be difficult (but may require a bit of JS to POST on selection change). If no, then I don't see any way that wouldn't require any JS.

Comment: If second select options depend on first select choice I think I need to POST/reload second select at least, otherwise how do you think I change second select options depending on the first select choice without POST/reload?